# why scala compiler says type arguments does not conform to bounds?

Tags: scala, matrix, types, type-parameter, f-bounded-polymorphism

I created Combiner trait with subclasses Complex and IntCombiner and my objective is to make Matrix work with both Complex and Int. But some reason it dosen't compile saying that

```
[com.implicits.TestImplicits1.IntCombiner] do not conform to class Matrix's type parameter bounds [T <: com.implicits.TestImplicits1.Combiner[T]]
    val m1 = new Matrix[IntCombiner](3, 3)((1 to 9).sliding(3).map {
```

But as my understanding goes as IntContainer is the subclass of Combiner it should work. Why such an error please explain ?

```
object TestImplicits1 {

  trait Combiner[T] {

    def +(b: T): T

    def *(b: T): T

  }

  class Complex(r: Double, i: Double) extends Combiner[Complex] {

    val real = r

    val im = i

    override def +(b: Complex): Complex = {
      new Complex(real + b.real, im + b.im)
    }

    override def *(b: Complex): Complex = {
      new Complex((real * b.real) - (im * b.im), real * b.im + b.real * im)
    }

  }

  class IntCombiner(a: Int) extends Combiner[Int] {
    val v = a

    override def *(b: Int): Int = v * b

    override def +(b: Int): Int = v + b

  }

  class Matrix[T <: Combiner[T]](x1: Int, y1: Int)(ma: Seq[Seq[T]]) {

    self =>
    val x: Int = x1
    val y: Int = y1

    def dot(v1: Seq[T], v2: Seq[T]): T = {
      v1.zip(v2).map { t: (T, T) => {
        t._1 * t._2
      }
      }.reduce(_ + _)
    }

  }

  object MatrixInt extends App {
    def apply[T <: Combiner[T]](x1: Int, y1: Int)(s: Seq[Seq[T]]) = {
      new Matrix[T](x1, y1)(s)
    }

    val m1 = new Matrix[IntCombiner](3, 3)((1 to 9).sliding(3).map {
      x => x map { y => new IntCombiner(y) }
    }.toSeq)
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem is here `T <: Combiner[T]` here you are saying you want a T which is a Combiner of itself - that is call **F-Bounded** _types_. Whereas, what you are trying to achieve looks more like a **typeclass** - in such case you want something like `T : Combiner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F-bounded polymorphism cannot be added to an existing `Int` class, because `Int` is just what it is, it does not know anything about your `Combiner` traits, so it cannot extend `Combiner[Int]`. You could wrap every `Int` into something like an `IntWrapper <: Combiner[IntWrapper]`, but this would waste quite a bit of memory, and library design around F-bounded polymorphism tends to be tricky.

Here is a proposal based on ad-hoc polymorphism and typeclasses instead:

```
object TestImplicits1 {

  trait Combiner[T] {
    def +(a: T, b: T): T
    def *(a: T, b: T): T
  }

  object syntax {
    object combiner {
      implicit class CombinerOps[A](a: A) {
        def +(b: A)(implicit comb: Combiner[A]) = comb.+(a, b)
        def *(b: A)(implicit comb: Combiner[A]) = comb.*(a, b)
      }
    }
  }

  case class Complex(re: Double, im: Double)

  implicit val complexCombiner: Combiner[Complex] = new Combiner[Complex] {

    override def +(a: Complex, b: Complex): Complex = {
      Complex(a.re + b.re, a.im + b.im)
    }

    override def *(a: Complex, b: Complex): Complex = {
      Complex((a.re * b.re) - (a.im * b.im), a.re * b.im + b.re * a.im)
    }

  }

  implicit val intCombiner: Combiner[Int] = new Combiner[Int] {
    override def *(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a * b
    override def +(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
  }

  class Matrix[T: Combiner](entries: Vector[Vector[T]]) {
    def frobeniusNormSq: T = {
      import syntax.combiner._
      entries.map(_.map(x => x * x).reduce(_ + _)).reduce(_ + _)
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know what you attempted with `dot` there, your `x1`, `x2` and `ma` seemed to be completely unused, so I added a simple square-of-Frobenius-norm example instead, just to show how the typeclasses and the syntactic sugar for operators work together. Please don't expect anything remotely resembling "high performance" from it - JVM traditionally never cared about rectangular arrays and number crunching (at least not on a single compute node; Spark & Co is a different story). At least your code won't be automatically transpiled to optimized CUDA code, that's for sure.

Comment: Just a couple of comments. First, why using an implicit conversion and a normal class, instead of an implicit class together with a value class.
Second, the `ComplexCombiner` is not implicit.
Third, why implicit objects instead of implicit vals? - implicit objects may cause problems given they have their own type.
Fourth, you may mark the case class `final`.
If you want, I can propose an edit with these changes.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez 1) Fixed; 2) Fixed, thanks. 3) Laziness (my laziness, not FP-laziness); Fixed. 4) One can extend case classes, what, really? Why... Ok, whatever. I guess I'll just have to wait until there is a proper syntax for [ADTs](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/adts.html), it doesn't seem to require `final` or any other C++ nostalgia rituals...

Comment: Yeah, you can extend case classes, you shouldn't, and anybody insane enough to try it deserves all the problems that it implies... but the problem is that many newbies to the language don't know about ADT's and sometimes they try to extends case classes _(I was there)_. So yes, I'm anxious too for **Scala 3** to provide good support for them and to replace value classes with _opaque types_.